# How to create a sparse matrix using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix in scipy/numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have to create a sparse matrix in python using a function similar to the Matlab function
S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n) where i, j, and v such that S(i(k),j(k)) = v(k) and the size of S is specified as m-by-n.

I have chosen the function scipy.sparse.csr_matrix to do this. My code is something like the following.

```
arg_shape=np.array([ndof,ndof])
K = csr_matrix((arg_data,(arg_x,arg_y)),shape=arg_shape)
```

here ndof=786432 and arg_data, arg_x, arg_y are numpy arrays and all of the same shape.i.e. (150994944,).

when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

In Matlab the code looks like this and works:

```
K = sparse(arg_x,arg_y,arg_data, ndof, ndof);
```

Could anyone please help me with the following points:
1). Is scipy.sparse.csr_matrix a good replacement for the Matlab spare function.
2). If yes, what is the mistake I am making in the code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are translating code from Matlab to Python/NumPy, your indices might be off by one.  Python indices start at 0, while Matlab indices start at 1.

Comment: Use `np.max((arg_x, arg_y), axis = 1)` to check if they are less or equal to `ndof`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion